# make a QGraphicsItemGroup with two QGraphicsSimpleTextItem-s?

Tags: linux, c++11, qt5

Assume I want to display in some [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html) a simple genealogy tree. Each person there has exactly a first name and a last name (and nothing else displayed).

For each person there, I want to build a [QGraphicsItemGroup](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitemgroup.html) made of two [QGraphicsSimpleTextItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicssimpletextitem.html)-s vertically aligned and centered. One for first names of persons, one for their family names. Each having its own font & color. I don't want to use a heavy [QGraphicsTextItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicstextitem.html) because it is too heavy (a person name with first and last names only don't deserve a full-fledged [QTextDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html)).

So I was thinking of

```
 struct Person {
   QGraphicsItemGroup _group;
   QGraphicsLinearLayout _lay;
   QGraphicsSimpleTextItem _firstname;
   QGraphicsSimpleTextItem _lastname;
 public:
   Person(QGraphicsScene*scene, 
          const std::string& first, const std::string& last) 
   : group(), _lay(Qt::Vertical), 
     _firstname(first.c_str()), _lastname(last.c_str()) {
      _lay.addItem(&_firstname);
      _lay.setSpacing(0, 5);
      _lay.addItem(&_lastname);
      _group.addToGroup(&_firstname);
      _group.addToGroup(&_lastname);
      scene->addItem(&_group);
   };
 };
```

but this don't work because `_lay.addItem(&_firstname);` don't compile, since a `QGraphicsSimpleTextItem` is not a `QGraphicsLayoutItem`

Any hints? Or is my entire approach wrong?

Should I define a class inheriting both from `QGraphicsSimpleTextItem` and from `QGraphicsLayoutItem` ?

<sup>NB: the actual code (GPlv3 licensed) is in my [basixmo](https://github.com/bstarynk/basixmo) project on *github*, file [guiqt.cc](https://github.com/bstarynk/basixmo/blob/master/guiqt.cc), commit [99fd6d7c1ff261](https://github.com/bstarynk/basixmo/commit/99fd6d7c1ff26102e89458d841cc1e2759841dcc). It is not a genealogy project, but an abstract syntax tree editor like thing for an interpreter with persistence. The concerned class is `BxoCommentedObjrefShow`; instead of a first name, I am showing an id like `_7rH2hUnmW63o78UGC`, instead of the last name, I am showing a short comment like `body of test1_ptrb_get`. The [basixmo](https://github.com/bstarynk/basixmo) project itself is a tentative rewrite of [melt-monitor-2015](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015) in C++11 & Qt5</sup>

Comment: Nobody have any clues about that question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem you supposed a purpose to the QGraphicsLinearLayout which is not its real purspose:

From [Official QT 5.7 documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicslinearlayout.html)

> The QGraphicsLinearLayout class provides a horizontal or vertical layout for managing **widgets** in Graphics View

It is not supposed to layout normal drawing items in you scene, but QWidgets. Unfortunately, the documentation and examples about it seem not to work.

**How to implement vertical layout**

Fortunately, the QGraphicsItem is not difficult to extends, so you may implement your pair of text in few lines:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsSimpleTextItem>
#include <QGraphicsItemGroup>

class QGraphicsPerson: public QGraphicsItemGroup
{
public:
    QGraphicsPerson( const QString& firstStr,
                     const QString& secondStr,
                     QGraphicsItem *parent=nullptr)
    {
        first.setText(firstStr);
        second.setText(secondStr);
        addToGroup(&first);
        addToGroup(&second);
        second.setPos(first.pos().x(), first.pos().y()+first.boundingRect().height());
    }

protected:
    QGraphicsSimpleTextItem first, second;
};

int main(int n, char **args)
{
    QApplication app(n, args);

    QGraphicsScene scene;
    QGraphicsView window(&scene);

    QGraphicsPerson person( "Adrian", "Maire");
    scene.addItem(&person);
    person.setPos(30,30);

    QGraphicsPerson person2( "Another", "Name");
    scene.addItem(&person2);

    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Note: Scene space extends to the infinite in both direction, so space management is very simplified (no minimum/maximum sizes, stretching, etc.)